# iPad iOS 5 with asp.net menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipad, menu, ios5

I'm developing an intranet site that uses asp.net menu tag, and on hovering over a specific link, the submenu pops up.

The one thing we have to include is support for iPhone and iPad.  The site for the iPhone is going to be completely different, so this will not be an issue.  However, on the iPad, there are no significant changes to the site itself from that of a desktop / laptop user.

The problem I was having was that after upgrading to iOS 5 was that the built in onMouseOver event from the asp menu isn't firing (meaning that when I would tap the menu item once, it would act like I had tapped it twice).  In iOS 4.+ the control would work fine (tap once to get the list of menu items and then tap again to follow a link).

I've implemented a workaround suggested by [this Code Project post](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/278315/asp-net-4-0-menu-control-and-iPad?display=Print), implementing a mouseover event that calls a null javascript function.

A small Markup to illustrate the problem:

```
<asp:Menu runat="server" ID="Menu1" /* Any other control additions here */>
  <Items>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuItem1" Value="MenuItem1" />
     <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuItem2" Value="MenuItem2" />
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

And how I implemented the fix:

```
MenuItem mnu_itm = new MenuItem();
mnu_itm.Text = "ADMIN";
mnu_itm.Value = "";
mnu_itm.NavigateUrl = "javascript:(function(){})();";
```

Also: Sorry if there is a similar question, I couldn't find it.

**Edit**

After doing a bit of testing on this, I've found that this will only work if the original menu item is not intended to actually go anywhere.  However, that's not necessarily always the case.  So this is actually a bigger problem than I thought.

I changed the (now not so simple) workaround to encompass this situation by using the MenuItemClick event, ViewState and checking the UserAgent (maybe not the most elegant solution, but it fits my needs)

```
string ItemNavUrl = Menu1.SelectedItem.NavigateUrl;
string ItemName = Menu1.SelectedItem.Text;

//Check the ViewState first, just in case another menu item was clicked.  
if (ViewState["MenuItemNav"] != null && Menu1.SelectedItem.NavigateUrl == "" && ViewState["MenuItemName"] != null && (string)ViewState["MenuItemName"] == Menu1.SelectedItem.Text)
{
    Menu1.SelectedItem.NavigateUrl = (string)ViewState["MenuItemNav"];
}
//Check to see if: 1. The item has a submenu 
//2. The Item also has a valid URL to send to, and 
//3. If the device is an iPad 
else if(Menu1.SelectedItem.ChildItems.Count > 0 && Menu1.SelectedItem.NavigateUrl != "" && Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("iPad") > -1) 
{
   //Set the URL to nothing and save the values for later.
   Menu1.SelectedItem.NavigateUrl = "";
   ViewState.Add("MenuItemNav", ItemNavUrl);
   ViewState.Add("MenuItemName", ItemName);
}
```

This is even less "elegant" than the previous solution (although more encompassing, although to be fair, I haven't thrown nearly as much testing into it as I'd like).

So I have a few questions here. Namely:

1. Is there any better way to do this that doesn't seem so hack-ish?
2. Is this a bug with iOS or just asp.net Menu (or at all?) Are there other controls that this will be needed on (that you know of)?

**Edit (3/21/2012):**  I have confirmed that this is still an issue for iOS 5.1.  My workaround still gives me what I need, but it still just seems like I'm working around a bug or something similar.